# PHP Displaying an array_filtered result using foreach seems wrong - Is there a less dirty way?

Tags: php, functional-programming

We have an array of pets, with name and species defined.

```
$dogs = array_filter($pets, 
    fn($v) => $v["species"]=="Dog");

foreach($dogs as $row) echo $row["name"];
```

The foreach to display the result seems so wrong after such a beautiful arrow function.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what output do you get or error message

Comment: `print_r($dogs);` how does it work

Comment: "Beautiful " is highly subjective ... I prefer code that "tells" me what is going on at a glance, over fancy nested specific array functions a lot of the time. But maybe you are happier here with something like one `echo implode(', ', array_column($dogs, 'name'));` instead ...

Comment: Thank you CBroe. That's exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(array_filter($pets, 
    fn($v) => $v["species"]=="Dog") as $row) echo $row["name"];
```

or, replacing the foreach loop with implode() and array_column():

```
echo implode(", ", 
        array_column(
            array_filter($pets, fn($v) => $v["species"]=="Dog"), 
            "name")
    );
```

The latter would I guess be more strictly functional.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter

```
<?php

    $pets = array(
        array('name'=>'Jack', 'species'=>'Dog'),
        array('name'=>'Jina', 'species'=>'Cat')
     );

     function select_dog($var)
     {
        return $var["species"]=="Dog";
     }

    $dogs = array_filter($pets, 'select_dog');

    foreach($dogs as $row) echo $row["name"]

?>
```